# How to schedule http invocation of authenticated cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a sort-of infrequently used cloud function that has a slow cold start latency. I want to reduce this latency by keeping the function warm. This function is normally only called by an app engine app, so it has restricted Cloud Invoker permissions. Cloud Scheduler seems like a good candidate for pinging the function to keep it warm. It seems that direct http invocation of the function is necessary. Even though the common convention is to schedule functions useing pub/sub, a single function can't be both http-triggered and pubsub-triggered.

I set my Cloud Scheduler job as follows, but still getting PERMISSION_DENIED error when it runs. Is something configured wrong, or is Cloud Scheduler not able to call an authentication function directly over http? One suspicion is that the Audience parameter is not really the "target_audience" parameter that Cloud Functions expects, but the standard "aud" parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several potential problems to investigate:

1) Do you have the permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for the service account?

When Cloud Scheduler creates tokens from a service account, it needs the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs`. This is in the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`. Add this role to the `Cloud Scheduler Service Agent` (notice the word Agent).

2) Is Cloud Run allowing this service account permissions?

Unless you have enabled the `allUsers` you need to add the service account to Cloud Run.
This is in the "Show Info Panel" under the "Permissions" tab. You can also add this via the CLI with the `--service-account` command-line option.

Comment: Thanks! Bullet point 1 fixed the issue. I didn't realize Cloud Scheduler also has its own service account that needs to be configured.

Comment: BTW, ignore my original comment about it not working that is now deleted. I was still getting failure, but didn't look deeper into the logs to see that it was no no longer an auth issue but rather a 400 from a missing query string param my function requires.

Comment: Just an update, you can no longer add a certain permission on a role created by GCP. Only custom roles can be edited.

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo - How does your comment apply to my answer? Google Cloud has never supported editing Google Cloud preconfigured roles.

Comment: @JohnHanley you mentioned adding a certain role to Cloud Scheduler Service agent. Could you clarify what it meant? I know that this answer worked for OP but from what I understand, you were asking us to add a role to a role (which I find slightly confusing). Do you mean adding the role on a service account with `Cloud Scheduler Service Agent` role?

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo - Service Agents are service accounts. You can add one or several roles to a service account. Do not confuse with roles with similar names.